# How to handle the multiple-line pattern in Python regular expression matching

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a list of company names to be replaced by the word 'company'. The list across multiple lines.

```
cmp=re.compile(""" A | B |
                   C | D
               """)
text='A is a great company, so is B'
cmp.sub('company',text)
```

But it doesn't work. How should I fix this?

Edit:

The above example given didn't consider the whitespace in company names.

```
company1=re.compile(r"""Berkshire Hathaway|Australia & New Zealand Bank
                  |Wells Fargo|AIG
                  |Ind & Comm Bank of China|BNP Paribas""")
company2=re.compile(r"""Berkshire Hathaway|Australia & New Zealand Bank
                  |Wells Fargo|AIG
                  |Ind & Comm Bank of China|BNP Paribas""",re.VERBOSE)
text='AIG is a great company, so is Berkshire Hathaway'  
company1.sub('cmp',text) 
>>> 'AIG is a great company, so is cmp'
company2.sub('cmp',text) 
>>> 'cmp is a great company, so is Berkshire Hathaway'
```

Comment: What is `text`?

Comment: Have you considered removing the newline (and possibly the spaces as well) from your pattern? If you require the newline as a separator, replace it with e.g. a space.

Comment: Consider using plain `str.replace`, iterating over the company names.

Comment: @Evert How to remove newline from patterns?

Comment: Try `re.compile(""" A | B |
                   C | D
               """, flags=re.VERBOSE)` to ignore newlines

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks. However my company names contains space(see updated example). Any idea on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could treat this as an example of a verbose pattern which allows (and ignores) whitespace like line breaks:

```
import re

cmp = re.compile(r""" A | B |
                   C | D
               """, re.VERBOSE)
text = 'A is a great company, so is B'
print(cmp.sub('company', text))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
company is a great company, so is company
```

> Space is contained in the company names. ... Any idea on how to fix
>   this?

We need to do something like a CGI escape of the space characters that appear inside of names.  Here's a regex-based approach that doesn't require decoding of the encoded spaces:

```
import re

companies = re.compile(re.sub(r"(?<=\S) (?=\S)", r"[ ]", """Berkshire Hathaway|Australia & New Zealand Bank
                  |Wells Fargo|AIG
                  |Ind & Comm Bank of China|BNP Paribas"""), re.VERBOSE)

text = 'AIG is a great company, so is Berkshire Hathaway'

print(companies.sub('cmp', text))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
cmp is a great company, so is cmp
```

Comment: My example is not so good. Space is contained in the company names.(see the updated example). Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @LeiHao, I've added a second example that addresses this issue.